# how to edit sqlite DB

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I create one application that store data from `NSDictionary` in **SQLite**. this `NSDictionary` get own information from many `NSArray` and store in **SQLite DB**. this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int number = [self GetNumberOfRecord]; //this method get number of rows in sqlite
    NSArray *idd = @[@"122", @"234", @"453", @"53464", @"4565", @"1111", @"2222"];
    NSArray *name = @[@"janatan", @"fred", @"john", @"cristiano", @"vein", @"emma", @"shyla"];
    NSArray *age = @[@"23", @"35", @"12", @"24", @"22", @"34", @"56"];
    NSArray *sex = @[@"male", @"male", @"male", @"male", @"male", @"famale", @"famale"];
    NSString *query2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from table1 where name = '%@'", [name lastObject]];
    //NSLog(@"query : %@", query2);
    BOOL recordExist = [self recordExistOrNot:query2];
    if (!recordExist) {
        for (int i = number; i < [idd count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *a = [idd objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *b = [name objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *c = [age objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *d = [sex objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into table1 (id, name, age, sex) values ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')", a, b, c, d];
            NSLog(@"%@", query);
            [self executeQuery:query];
        }
    }
}
```

I want two things but I not found any thing about it.

**First**: If in above code one or two of names changed (for example `NSArray` *name was:

```
{@"janatan", @"louis", @"john", @"fredrick", @"vein", @"emma", @"shyla"}
```

how I can edit my table **SQLite DB** and replace `louis` & `fredrick` instead `fred` & `cristiano`?)

**Second**: If in above code one or two names removed (for example `NSArray` *name was:

```
{@"janatan", @"john", @"vein", @"emma", @"shyla"}
```

how I can remove Record the name of the deleted?)

thanks a lot.

Comment: your data is dynamic or static, means how you get data from API(Server) or locally,static (as you describe here)?

Comment: with json from API server

Comment: my friend I get this data from json of API and possible changed.

Comment: once check with my answer.

Comment: Dude, use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Its a must if you are dealing with sqlite directly instead of coredata.

Comment: @mamnun += 1; Also use descriptive variable names. The purposes of `a`, `b`, … may be clear for you today, but won't be in a year or so, nor to anybody else reading your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you can use UPDATE Query.

try like this run for loop with unique identification value and update the values.

```
UPDATE table1 SET ContactName='newName' WHERE id=uniqu_id
```

Use this one.

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE table1 SET  name='%@' WHERE id='%@' ,[dic objectForKey:@"name"],[dic objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

`EDIT`:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE table1 SET  name='%@',age='%@' WHERE id='%@' ,[dic objectForKey:@"name"],[dic objectForKey:@"age"],[dic objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

Comment: what happend when you use this Query?

Comment: I not use still but I tell no need send this Query to Specified method?

Comment: my friend if I want to update name & age for one id what I do?

Comment: once check my edited one and you can update more fileds like this.

Comment: my friend for deleted what I do?

Comment: I want for example is_deleted was 0 deleted record else no deleted (is_deleted is array like name & age & ...)