# how to check exist NSMutableArray is table sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I have one application that store data in sqlite database. I can put many data in sqlite and my data changed. now I want to check that is the values of `NSMutableArray` in the table sqlite???
I beginning add this data in sqlite and now changed data and I want check and see if all array is in sqlite no update else if isn't update it
this my code :

```
NSArray *idd = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
NSArray *name = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mamali",@"fred",@"jjjjjj",@"saeid",@"john", nil];
NSArray *sex = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"male",@"male",@"male",@"male",@"male", nil];
NSArray *is_deleted = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1", nil];
for (int i = 0; i < [idd count]; i++)
{
    NSString * ID = [idd objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * NAME = [name objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * SEX = [sex objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * DEL = [is_deleted objectAtIndex:i];
    dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ID,@"id",NAME,@"name",SEX,@"sex",DEL,@"deleted", nil];
    if (!all) {
        all = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [all addObject:dic];
}
```

so tell me how check see all is in sqlite or no???

Comment: http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-SDK-Database-Insert-Update-Delete-with-SQLite-and-Objective-C-C-How-To,http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Comment: @estefan: what's the purpose of posting [almost the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331043/how-to-edit-sqlite-db) (and clearly related) question twice from different SO accounts?

Comment: Well, you do a query to see if the data is there, then update if it's changed, insert if it's new.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have memory management issues. Instead of your code, I am suggesting you to use this:

```
NSArray *identifiersArray = @[ @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5" ];
NSArray *namesArray = @[ @"mamali",@"fred",@"jjjjjj",@"saeid",@"john" ];
NSArray *sexArray = @[ @"male",@"male",@"male",@"male",@"male" ];
NSArray *isDeletedArray = @[ @"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1" ];

NSMutableArray *allArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[identifiersArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *identifier = [identifiersArray objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSString *name = [namesArray objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSString *sex = [sexArray objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSString *isDeletedStr = [isDeletedArray objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSDictionary *dic = @{ @"id" : identifier, @"name" : name, @"sex" : sex, @"deleted" : isDeletedStr };
    [allArray addObject:dic];
}];
```

Then you can insert data to sqlite database using similar approach:

```
// configuring SQL query
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into ..."];
sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    // insert successfully executed
    // all your data in database
}
```

Then you can select inserted data from sqlite database using similar approach:

```
// configuring select SQL query
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from ..."]
sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"[SQLITE] Error when preparing query!");
} else {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSMutableArray *row = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=0; i<sqlite3_column_count(statement); i++) {
            int colType = sqlite3_column_type(statement, i);
            id value;
            if (colType == SQLITE_TEXT) {
                const unsigned char *col = sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", col];
            } else if (colType == SQLITE_INTEGER) {
                int col = sqlite3_column_int(statement, i);
                value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:col];
            } else if (colType == SQLITE_FLOAT) {
                double col = sqlite3_column_double(statement, i);
                value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:col];
            } else if (colType == SQLITE_NULL) {
                value = [NSNull null];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"[SQLITE] UNKNOWN DATATYPE");
            }

            [row addObject:value];
        }
        [result addObject:row];
    }
    return result;
}
return nil;
```

Hope this will help you.
The sqlite code was taken from [here](http://jona.than.biz/blog/working-with-sqlite-in-objective-cios/).